# LeetCode 762 why is separate code works in Jupiter Notebook and not in Leetcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, primes

I am working on leetcode "762. Prime Number of Set Bits in Binary Representation" and I tested my code works fine on Jupiter Notebook and when I migrate into leetcode it shows null as a ending result. Could someone give me any hint on what the problems are?

```
class Solution:
    def countPrimeSetBits(self, L, R):
        """
        :type L: int
        :type R: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        def isPrime(num):
            if num == 0:
                return False
            list1 = list(range(num))
            list1.remove(0)
            if len(list1) != 0:
                list1.remove(num-1)
            for i in list1:
                if num % (i+1) == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return True

            count = 0
            for i in range(L, R+1):
                newlist = list(bin(i)[2::])
                newcount = 0
                for j in newlist:
                    if j == '1':
                        newcount += 1
                if isPrime(newcount) is True:
                    count += 1
            return count
```

The expect result is 23 for the first test case which is L=842 and R=888
Jupiter Note book gives me back 23 as expected but Leetcode returns null as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two serious problems.  The first is that the code as presented is indented incorrectly, such that the body of code for `countPrimeSetBits()` is instead part of the internal function `isPrime()`.  The second problem is that, besides being the worst implementation ever, your `isPrime()` doesn't really work:

```
>>> isPrime(169)
True
>>> 13 * 13
169
>>>
```

due to this `else` clause placing the `return` at the wrong point in the code:

```
else:
    return True
```

Below is your patched code which hopefully will work in both environments:

```
class Solution:

    def countPrimeSetBits(self, L, R):
        """
        :type L: int
        :type R: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        def isPrime(number):
            if number == 0:
                return False

            divisors = list(range(number))
            divisors.remove(0)
            if divisors:
                divisors.remove(number - 1)

            for divisor in divisors:
                if number % (divisor + 1) == 0:
                    return False

            return True

        count = 0

        for i in range(L, R + 1):
            newlist = list(bin(i)[2::])
            newcount = 0

            for j in newlist:
                if j == '1':
                    newcount += 1

            if isPrime(newcount):
                count += 1

        return count
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!